# Could not find stored procedure Excel VBA Error

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures

> Error occurs on this line of code

```
Set rs = conn.Execute("GetReportingHierarchy")
```

[image]

```
Sub RunCode()
Dim sConnString As String,conn As adodb.Connection,rs As adodb.Recordset

sConnString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;" & _
          "Data Source=MyServerIPAndPort" & _
          "Initial Catalog=MyDB;" & _
          "User Id=MyUserName;" & _
          "Password=MyPassword;"

sConnString = sConnString
Set conn = New adodb.Connection
Set rs = New adodb.Recordset

conn.Open sConnString
Set rs = conn.Execute("GetReportingHierarchy")

If Not rs.EOF Then
    Range("A6").CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
Else
    MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
End If

If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
   
End Sub
```

> SQL Server Stored Procedure

[image: SQL Server Stored Procedure]

Comment: It probably needs something like `"dbo.GetReportingHierarchy"`

Comment: Tried "dbo.GetReportingHierarchy" but throwing the same error.

Comment: I assume you have verified you're connected to the correct database and that your chosen user has the correct permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

It should be fully qualified reference.

```
Set rs = conn.Execute("MyDBName.dbo.GetReportingHierarchy")
```